# cats-effect:How to transform Map[x,IO[y]] to IO[Map[x,y]]

Tags: scala, io, scala-cats, io-monad, cats-effect

I have a map of string to IO like this `Map[String, IO[String]]`, I want to transform it into `IO[Map[String, String]]`. How to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to be a little careful with this one. Maps in Scala are unordered, so if you try to use cats's `sequence` like this…

```
import cats.instances.map._
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.UnorderedTraverse

object Example1 {
    type StringMap[V] = Map[String, V]
    val m: StringMap[IO[String]] = Map("1" -> IO{println("1"); "1"})
    val n: IO[StringMap[String]] = UnorderedTraverse[StringMap].unorderedSequence[IO, String](m)
}
```

you'll get the following error:

```
Error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.CommutativeApplicative[cats.effect.IO]
```

The issue here is that the IO monad is not actually commutative. Here is the [definition of commutativity](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors#Sequencing_of_effects):

```
map2(u, v)(f) = map2(v, u)(flip(f)) // Commutativity (Scala)
```

This definition shows that the result is the same even when the effects happen in a different order.

You can make the above code compile by providing an instance of `CommutativeApplicative[IO]` but that still doesn't make the IO monad commutative. If you run the following code you can see the side effects are not processed in the same order:

```
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.CommutativeApplicative

object Example2 {
  implicit object FakeEvidence extends CommutativeApplicative[IO] {
    override def pure[A](x: A): IO[A] = IO(x)
    override def ap[A, B](ff: IO[A => B])(fa: IO[A]): IO[B] =
      implicitly[Applicative[IO]].ap(ff)(fa)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def flip[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C) = (b: B, a: A) => f(a, b)
    val fa = IO{println(1); 1}
    val fb = IO{println(true); true}
    val f  = (a: Int, b: Boolean) => s"$a$b"
    println(s"IO is not commutative: ${FakeEvidence.map2(fa, fb)(f).unsafeRunSync()} == ${FakeEvidence.map2(fb, fa)(flip(f)).unsafeRunSync()} (look at the side effects above^^)")
  }
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
1
true
true
1
IO is not commutative: 1true == 1true (look at the side effects above^^)
```

In order to get around this I would suggest making your map something with an order, like a List, where sequence will not require commutativity. The following example is just one way to do this:

```
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._

object Example3 {
  val m: Map[String, IO[String]] = Map("1" -> IO {println("1"); "1"})
  val l: IO[List[(String, String)]] = m.toList.traverse[IO, (String, String)] { case (s, io) => io.map(s2 => (s, s2))}
  val n: IO[Map[String, String]] = l.map { _.toMap }
}
```

Comment: @codenooddle How to perform map IO operations in parallel?

Answer (score 15):

It would be nice to use `unorderedTraverse` here, but as codenoodle pointed out, it doesn't work because `IO` is not a commutative applicative. However there is a type that is, and it's called `IO.Par`. Like the name suggests, its `ap` combinator won't execute things sequentially but in parallel, so it's commutative – doing a and then b is not the same as doing b and then a, but doing a and b concurrently *is* the same as doing b and a concurrently.

So you can use `unorderedTraverse` using a function that doesn't return `IO` but `IO.Par`. However the downside to that is that now you need to convert from `IO` to `IO.Par` and then back – hardly an improvement.

To solve this problem, I have added the `parUnorderedTraverse` method in cats 2.0 that will take care of these conversions for you. And because it all happens in parallel it will also be more efficient! There are also `parUnorderedSequence`, `parUnorderedFlatTraverse` and `parUnorderedFlatSequence`.

I should also point out that this works not only for `IO` but also for everything else with a `Parallel` instance, such as `Either[A, ?]` (where `A` is a `CommutativeSemigroup`). It should also be possible for `List`/`ZipList`, but nobody appears to have bothered to do it yet.